# How can I clean a PDB file using VMD or NAMD?

Tags: protein-structure, pdb, protein-protein-interaction

I have 3884 PDB files generated by [pd2_ca2main](http://www.sbg.bio.ic.ac.uk/%7Ephyre2/PD2_ca2main/). PD2 CA2main is server for reconstructing the backbone of Calpha proteins using Gaussian mixture models.

All of these files have duplicate atoms or alternate coordinates.

How can I clean these PDB files using Visual Molecular Dynamics ([VMD](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/SumSchool/materials/sources/tutorials/01-vmd-tutorial/html/node2.html)) or Scaleable Molecular Dynamics (NAMD) *****?

Can anyone tell me what command I should use in console mode?

***** note, this server may be unavailable

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Chimera](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/) for this. The following code cleans your pdb file and write new pdb file.

```
import chimera
from DockPrep import prep
from chimera import runCommand, openModels

models = chimera.openModels.list(modelTypes=[chimera.Molecule])
prep(models)
runCommand("write format pdb 0 molecule.pdb")
```

You can run the code with

```
 chimera --nogui file.pdb code.py
```

Comment: how do I get chimera ?  pip install pychimera https://pypi.org/project/pychimera/ ??? is there a python3 version ?

Comment: https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/download.html

Comment: https://pychimera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ --> Use UCSF Chimera packages in any Python 2.7 interpreter